# Store information on page reload in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-services

in my app i'm storing information into service to avoid the local storage and the possibility to leak information about the variable i need to know into a particular page. The problem is when the user reload the page (ctrl + f5 or cmd +R for clarity) because the service reset the informations stored in it. Is there any way to save this data temporarily just before the reload and restore after it finished? (Maybe passing for the localstorage or similar)
In case that isn't the best scenario to store information, is there any other ways to do?